# iOS - UIButton enabling/disabling two or more buttons in a single strike

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have three buttons assigned to the property "botao2" (like a calculator, for example).

When I mouse over the circle on the left (@property on the .h file) only one button is highlighted.

When I mouse over the - (IBAction) (on the .m file) all the three buttons get highlighted...

And when I try do disable botao2 (_botao2.enabled = FALSE;) it really works (all three buttons are disabled), but when I click the original button (the one highlighted on .h file) it does not even change it's collor (it is really disabled!).

The other two buttons are disabled as well, but when I click on them I see a collor change (blue when I click and back to white when I release).

Is it just a simulator glitch or is it possible to set all buttons disabled like the original one (the one of the .h file)?

Comment: How do you assign three buttons to a single property (I guess it is IBOutlet) ?

Comment: yes. you are right... the property gets a single button... IBAction has the three of them... noob's misunderstanding :-)

Comment: but the question persists! will I have to create a different property foe each button to get what I want?? Is it about disabling the IBAction as a whole??

Comment: Perhaps you may be better off using UISegmentedControl with three segments.

Comment: The outlet stores a reference for a single control, if you want to manipulate three controls from the code, you need to have three outlets, one per button. The same action (IBAction) could be used for different events and different controls, the `sender` parameter (as it is called at default generated signatures) will be a reference for the control triggering the action. Please check `enabled` property [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) to understand it better.

Comment: Thanks! So, I will assume that I must have as many outlets as buttons count... no problem... I will use if-then-else to control the IBAction, so that all the buttons will perform the same way.